added source files from older version, having issue Ubuntu 24.04
I installed ubuntu 24 a week ago, and I was having issues while installing some packages thru terminal, and i followed some things and now my sudo commands says:
"E: Type 'deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read."
I followed these while adding the files, and I want to undo this. Please help!!
Ubuntu sudo apt get update 404 Not Found problem

AFAIK in a default installation of Ubuntu 24.04, /etc/apt/sources.list would be an empty file, with sources defined instead (in DEB822-style format) via /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

This question is similar to: How do I fix this "E: Type '*' is not known on line * in source list ..." update error?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
